# Github actions workflow doesn’t run on pull request when pull request is created by another workflow action and have conflict

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 workflow file.
One is test.xml and other is merge.xml

The test.xml run php unit test and if the test successful it will create a pull request to staging branch (the test.xml run in feature branch).

The strange is, if the pull request have conflict, the merge.xml workflow will not triggered. But when the pull request don't have any conflict, it will run and merge the pull request. Did my xmls are misconfiguration?

Here is the xmls.

**Test.xml**

```
name: Test
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - staging
jobs:
  run-test:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
       - name: run test
  pullrequest-to-staging:
    needs: [run-test]
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout current branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Create Pull Request to staging
        uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }}
          pr_title: "Pulling ${{ steps.branch_name.outputs.branch }} into staging"
          pr_body: ":crown: *An automated PR*"
          destination_branch: "staging"
          pr_label: "automerge"
```

**merge.xml**

```
name: merge-to-staging
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging
jobs:
  merge-to-staging:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Label merge conflicts
        uses: eps1lon/actions-label-merge-conflict@v2.0.0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }}"
          dirtyLabel: "conflicts"
          continueOnMissingPermissions: true
      - name: Merge to staging
        uses: pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.12.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }}"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, the action that should be triggered by `pull_request` is not going to run if the pull request has merge conflicts. It's a limitation of GitHub Actions as described here: https://github.community/t/run-actions-on-pull-requests-with-merge-conflicts/17104/2

Answer (score 2):

[From GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request), this is expected

> Note: Workflows will not run on pull_request activity if the pull request has a merge conflict. The merge conflict must be resolved first.

They also document that `pull_request_target` can be used then:

> Along with a solution solution: Conversely, workflows with the
> pull_request_target event will run even if the pull request has a
> merge conflict. Before using the pull_request_target trigger, you
> should be aware of the security risks. For more information, see
> pull_request_target.