# GitHub action on pull_request close does not run when branch is not merged

Tags: github-actions

I've noticed that, sometimes (or perhaps all the time), a GH action in the form of:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
```

does not run when a PR is closed without merge. Is the above syntax the correct syntax for that?  The action always runs when a PR is merged, so it's just the "close-no-merge" case that is failing. Thanks!

Comment: Did the PR have conflicts? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65047992/3001761, https://github.community/t/action-for-pull-request-closed-does-not-run-when-merged-false/17410/3.

Comment: Works for me with a minimal workflow and closing a PR without merging

Comment: I noticed that too! Glad to hear I'm not crazy...