# Github workflow event trigger synchronize not working?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have the following github workflow definition:

```
name: Build

on:
    pull_request:
        types: [ opened, edited, synchronize ]
        paths-ignore:
            - '**.md'
    push:
        branches: 
            - main
jobs:
    get-job:
        name: My job
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

            - name: Say hello
              run: |
                    echo Hello!
```

1. I create a pull request from the head-branch to base-branch. The workflow is triggered as expected.
2. I commit and push a change to head-branch. The workflow is triggered as expected.
3. I commit and push another change to head-branch. The workflow is NOT triggered as expected:

[image: Synchronize not working]

I have read the documentation and other sources, all of which describe the synchronize type as the type I need to use to ensure every new change in the PR triggers the workflow. Why does it work intermitently?

Comment: What a surprise, I'm facing the same issue right now. It only ran for 1 of my 10 commits. Maybe a possible problem on GitHub side? or there is something to take care of that we don't know while updating workflows?

Comment: Is there a commit `k` after `j`? And what is in commit `i` and `j`?

Comment: Did it run eventually? Sometimes GitHub Actions has an outage and does not immediately trigger builds. There can be queues for up to 1 hour (because after 1 hour items are dropped from the build queue).

Comment: @Herman it never ran

Comment: @Th3B0Y Same issue here, did you figure it out?

Comment: @ŠimonTóth unfortunately nothing changed

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was being caused due to the fact that the head branch and base branch of my PR had conflicts. I figured this out thanks to this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65236345/2121777) and no thanks due to github actions output which gave no clue of this whatsoever.